# How do I set a system variable for use in a maven failsafe test?

Tags: java, maven, maven-failsafe-plugin, system-variable, integration-testing

I'm trying to run tests on a buildserver that doesn't have the environment variable I need set.

The variable is used from within a spring context xml file to resolve the location of property files.

e.g. classpath:config/${EnvironmentType}/myfile.properties

I'm using the failsafe plugin and trying the various documented methods (even deprecated ones) for setting the variables. None of it makes a lick of difference, the variable is never resolved.

My config is below :

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.12</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>Integration tests against mocks</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>${skip.integration.mock.tests}</skipTests>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*ITMock.java</include>
                        </includes>
                        <argLine>-DEnvironmentType="DevelopmentIntegration"</argLine>
                        <systemPropertyVariables>
                            <EnvironmentType>DevelopmentIntegration</EnvironmentType>
                        </systemPropertyVariables>
                        <environmentVariables>
                            <EnvironmentType>DevelopmentIntegration</EnvironmentType>
                        </environmentVariables>
                        <systemProperties>
                            <property>
                                <name>EnvironmentType</name>
                                <value>DevelopmentIntegration</value>
                            </property>
                        </systemProperties>
                        <forkMode>false</forkMode>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>Verify</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <skipTests>false</skipTests>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

How can I get this env var set for my tests without actually setting it on the machine?

Note : Running this with mvn verify -DEnvironmentType="DevelopmentIntegration" works. I want it to work with just mvn verify.

Cheers,
Peter

Comment: Have you tried to update the version to 2.12.2 cause this version is in accordance with the documentation? Furthermore have you checked the output via mvn -X ...

Comment: PEBKAC... The config above is in a parent project, I failed to notice it was being overridden by one of the child projects. I stuck with 2.12 as my version. 2.12.2 breaks because it doesn't create the failsafe report directory.

Comment: Thank you. I had to search a lot to get this done and your question answered my question. The documentation on the failsafe plugin is just so sparse and so many links on the internet just give a page not found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config shown has value `false` for `<forkMode>`, which doesn't appear to be a valid value for this parameter per the [docs](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-failsafe-plugin/integration-test-mojo.html).

I believe that the environment and system variables specified in the plugin configuration do *not* apply to the currently running JVM; they apply if the plugin creates a new JVM for running the tests.  My guess is that the `false` value in the forkMode parameter is causing the forking not to happen.  Try leaving it at the default (`once`) and see if that works.

Comment: I'll give you an accept for responding. The fork mode is wrong, but that wasn't the problem. (It actually just blows up if that config gets used.) I was overriding the config in a child project so my settings were being ignored.